# R error in geom(line): Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2296) ✖ Fix the following mappings: `y

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, aesthetics

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWUdj.png)
For a university course i have to plot the inferred excess mortality up until 2019 and as of 2020. However, when running my code it keeps saying i have an aes error: Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2296)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `y`

How could i solve this issue, i have tried the solutions shown on https://www.statology.org/aesthetics-must-be-either-length-1-or-same-as-data/ without any luck

Any help is appreciated!
my code:

```
ggplot(data=preds[preds$YEAR<=2019,], aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(WEEK)), y=1E7*preds$excess_deaths/POPULATION), colour = factor(YEAR)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=1E7*preds$excess_deaths/POPULATION, colour = NA)) +
  geom_ribbon(data=preds[preds$YEAR<=2019,], aes(ymin=1E7*preds$lower.CI/POPULATION, ymax=1E7*preds$upper.CI/POPULATION), colour=NA, alpha=I(0.4)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=1E7*preds$excess_deaths.lower.PI/POPULATION, ymax=1E7*preds$excess_deaths.upper.PI/POPULATION), colour=NA, alpha=I(0.2)) + 
  geom_line(data=preds[preds$YEAR>=2020,], aes(y=1E7*preds$excess_deaths/POPULATION, colour = NA)) +
  geom_ribbon(data=preds[preds$YEAR>=2020,], 
              aes(ymin=1E7*preds$excess_deaths.lower.CI/POPULATION, ymax=1E7*preds$excess_deaths.upper.CI/POPULATION), colour=NA, alpha=I(0.4)) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=preds[preds$YEAR>=2020,], 
              aes(ymin=1E7*preds$excess_deaths.lower.PI/POPULATION, ymax=1E7*preds$excess_deaths.upper.PI/POPULATION), colour=NA, alpha=I(0.2)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ model, ncol = 1) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Excess mortality (Per 10M inhabitants") +
  ggtitle(label = 'EXCESS MORTALITY IN BELGIUM PER WEEK (PER 10M INHABITANTS)', subtitle = 'Data Statbel 2009-2022') +
  theme_economist_white()
```

Trying to change the color and fill functions of aes according to multiple sites without any luck. Expecting the color to resemble each year. when running i received this error: Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2296)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `y`

Comment: genenrally try to do the calcualtions and filtering before the plotting, so you know whats the problem with your code(and you can reuse code more easily)

Comment: There are errors in the code and it is difficult to make heads or tails without seeing a sample of the data.  I am sure there is an easier way to do this.  First is step is to remove "preds$" from all of the `aes()` definitions.  When one uses "preds$" you are referencing back to the original data frame and not from  "data=".  I suggest simplify this code block down to 1 year and getting that to work before attempting multiple years.